# Minutiae Image Using OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project based on vascular pattern detection.
I have read this post [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/6364/fingerprint-matching-in-mobile-devices-android-platform/). I want to apply minutiae using OpenCV on the following image

[image: Result Image]

Using the Minutiae i have to find all the possible bifurcations and save them in a feature vector.

Comment: What attempts have you made so far?

Comment: I have read some details form this page [link](http://www.intechopen.com/books/biometrics/minutiae-based-fingerprint-extraction-and-recognition) but couldn't find any proper method our example code to implement.

Comment: The page you linked has an algorithm under section 5: Pixel-level approach.  It describes a kernel-based approach in which you iterate through each pixel and classify the pixel based on an analysis of a small, square region surrounding the pixel.  That might be a reasonable place to start.